# How to control #define directive in different projects ...?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My question is quite straight forward. I just intended to know that is the `#define` directive in C++ controllable over the different project files? Elaborately, I have a header file and a cpp file for one project. The codes of the files are as follows:

> **MyHeader.h**

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_H__

#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#ifdef _HEADER_EXPORT_
#define HEADER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HEADER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

class HEADER_API MyHeader
{
public:
    MyHeader();
    ~MyHeader();
#ifdef _HEADER_DISPLAY_
    void __cdecl ParseHeader();
#elif defined (_HEADER_RETURN_)
    string __cdecl ParseHeader();
#endif
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define __MY_HEADER_H__
#endif
```

> **MyHeader.cpp**

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_H__
#include "MyHeader.h"
#endif

MyHeader::MyHeader() { }
MyHeader::~MyHeader() { }

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef _HEADER_DISPLAY_
    HEADER_API void __cdecl MyHeader::ParseHeader()
    {
        fputs(string("Displaying...").c_str(), stdout);
    }
#elif defined (_HEADER_RETURN_)
    HEADER_API string __cdecl MyHeader::ParseHeader()
    {
        string retVal("Returning...");
        return retVal;
    }
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In another project *HeaderImpl.cpp* file has been implemented with the following code.

> **HeaderImpl.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define _HEADER_DISPLAY_ // To display the message

// #define _HEADER_RETURN_ // To return the message as string
#include "MyHeader.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyHeader header;
    MyHeader.ParseHeader(); // To display the message or to return the string
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I wanted to know that how can I use the `#define` directive in my `HeaderImpl.cpp` file to control the `ParseHeader` method for `MyHeader.cpp` file? As it has been noted that `MyHeader.h` file doing exactly what I need for; i.e. controlling the `ParseHeader` method upon declaring the `#define` directive, accordingly.

Comment: I would find another way to diversify your code between different projects, #define switching although efficient at runtime is really difficult to manage and confusing to read. Said that you can make definitions to compile against on all major compilers, VS included, just find the tab under project settings. You'll then want a different VS project with different #defines laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Each C++ source file is compiled independently, and settings in one cannot affect another. You'll have to do this on project level.

One way to do that would be to set up different project (and solution) configurations for different values of this macro. Instead of just the usual `Debug` and `Release`, you could add `Debug-Display`, `Debug-Return` etc. You can then define the macros in the project settings for each configuration. This will make sure you link the correctly built version of your library.

---

As a side note, you're using illegal names in your code. A name which contains double underscores, or starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, is reserved for the compiler & standard library. User code is not allowed to use such names for its own purposes.

Comment: ... in the same sense as all functions starting with a lower case letter might collide with a future version of the C standard library. "void HelloWorld()" is okay, "void hello_world()" is bad :) ...

Comment: @BitTickler No, not all names starting with a lowercase letter are reserved (but some are). Which is why newer additions to C (such as `_Bool` or `__restrict`) actually look the way they do.

Comment: These codes have just been illustrated for conveying my question only, which has no effect with the real one as I am implementing in real. And as you said @angew, if each C++ source file is compiled independently, which is more obvious very common, then how come we use a `#define` directive in C++ source code? For which reason it has also been implemented in lots of CRT and STL classes? Anyways, thank you for your precious time for showing me the light.

Comment: — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
— All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Comment: That's what the standard says. Even the compiler is banned from using double underscores or underscore followed by an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Lundin Which standard? In C++, such identifiers are "reserved to the implementation" (C++14 n4140 17.6.4.3.2/1). "The implementation" is the compiler + standard library.

Comment: @NiladriSen What do you mean? You can of course use a `#define` within a source file, it's just that such a define cannot affect *another* source file. Keep in mind that header files are *not* source files and are *not* compiled - they're textually "pasted" into a source file by `#include`.

Comment: While not currently able to prove with a link, I think some names were also reserved for "generated" code. Would be nice if anyone could tell me where I got that from to refresh my memory.

Comment: @Angew C11 7.1.3. I suppose C++ and C are different here.

Comment: @Lundin Very possible; this question's about C++, though.

Comment: @Angew So you mean including `#define _HEADER_RETURN_` in HeaderImpl.cpp will not allow me to call the `string __cdecl MyHeader::ParseHeader()` function as defined in MyHeader.cpp file ??

Comment: As for pre processor usage in C++: Just open the header ``functional`` and read. It is the cure to the myth that c++ obsoletes preprocessor. And while new standards arise, one of the oldest handicaps of C/C++ world is still not blessed with a solution: The include once problem. Be it ``#pragma(once)`` or the standard ``#ifndef __MODULE_NAME`` convention, it is up to the language standard to fix it, imho.

Comment: @NiladriSen Well, you will *seem* to be able to call the function (compilation will pass), but unless the macro was defined when compiling `MyHeader.cpp`, the function will not be implemented anywhere and so linking will fail.

Comment: @Angew Well, if you are able to find some source files of your own either in `_file.c` or `crtexe.c` or `dbgheap.c`; they all have a good implementation of `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` directives accordingly, which can easily be tampered through any .cpp file of one's implementation. As all of those files are pre-compiled then why on earth should they be manipulated during one's own implementation using either `#define _WIN64` or `#undef CRTDLL` or `#define WPRFLAG` manually ??

Comment: @NiladriSen I am no expert on the Windows C[++] runtime, but it's perfectly possible these files are compiled multiple times with different settings and all of the resulting object files are linked into the runtime library. Also, are you actually sure that if you `#define` one of these macros in one source file of yours, this will affect the behaviour of `crtexe` or some such?

Comment: @Angew Well, I am not pretty sure about the `crtexe` but you have been able to show me what was I looking for. Being unlucky to find a real solution though!

Comment: @NiladriSen I've added a possible project-scope solution to the answer.

Comment: @Angew By the way, if I really `#define` any of these aforesaid preprocessors, will not they thereby be affecting at all? What you think instead?

Answer (score 0):

You usually can provide #defines for all of your compilation units on the command line of the compiler. IIRC for Visual studio that would be something like `/D_HEADER_DISPLAY_` or `/D_HEADER_RETURN_`

Your project must be using something like this already for the `_HEADER_EXPORT_` define.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a preprocessor definition in one translation unit to remotely affect a different translation unit.

Most, if not all, compilers accept them as parameters for the compilation, though (and the flag is usually `-D`, or `/D` for VC++).

In Visual Studio, you can set project-wide preprocessor definitions in the project settings, under

```
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions
```

Comment: I am not asking that how to define a preprocessor in Visual Studio, rather willing to know about how differently to invoke a function using a `#define` directive, instead.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want different implementations of `ParseHeader` *in the same project*? (You can't.) You need project-wide definitions, or you can use *one* header containing the definitions that you include everywhere (this is the more portable solution).

Comment: So you mean including `#define _HEADER_RETURN_` in HeaderImpl.cpp will not allow me to call the `string __cdecl ParseHeader()` function as defined in MyHeader.cpp file ??

Comment: @NiladriSen That's pretty much what all these answers are saying, yes. The .cpp files are compiled separately, and every `#include "MyHeader.h"` is independent of all the others.

Comment: Well, if you are able to find some source files of your own either in `_file.c` or `crtexe.c` or `dbgheap.c`; they all have a good implementation of `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` directives accordingly, which can easily be tampered through any .cpp file of one's implementation. As all of those files are pre-compiled then why on earth should they be manipulated during one's own implementation using either `#define _WIN64` or `#undef CRTDLL` or `#define WPRFLAG` manually ??

Comment: @NiladriSen "which can easily be tampered through any .cpp file of one's implementation" Have you actually tried this? (You haven't.)

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it yet for those aforesaid files, though there are a number of source files to be implemented with, and from one of among them I once really had.